# Emacs comment-region in C mode

Tags: c, emacs, elisp, c-mode

In GNU Emacs, is there a good way to change the comment-region command in C mode from

```
/* This is a comment which extends  */
/* over more than one line in C. */
```

to

```
/* This is a comment which extends
   over more than one line in C. */
```

? I have tried

```
(setq comment-multi-line t)
```

but this does not help. There is a [section on multi-line comments in the Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Multi_002dLine-Comments), but it does not mention anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Emacs 21, there's been a module named [`'newcomment`](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/*checkout*/emacs/lisp/newcomment.el?root=emacs), which has different comment styles (see the variable `'comment-styles`.  This setting gets close to what you want:

```
(setq comment-style 'multi-line)
```

(Note: you should probably make that setting in `'c-mode-hook`).

However, none of the settings make the comments look like what you want.

The easiest way I saw to get what you want is to add this hack:

```
(defadvice comment-region-internal (before comment-region-internal-hack-ccs activate)
  "override 4th argument to be just spaces"
  (when (eq major-mode 'c-mode)  ; some condition here
    (let ((arg (ad-get-arg 4)))
      (when arg
        (ad-set-arg 4 (make-string (length arg) ?\ ))))))
```

The current settings for `comment-style` always prefix the comment lines with " * " (if not the whole " /* ").

If you don't have Emacs 21, I suppose you could simply download [`newcomment.el`](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/*checkout*/emacs/lisp/newcomment.el?root=emacs) from the repository.  I don't know if it works as-is in earlier versions of Emacs, but it might be worth a shot, though upgrading Emacs would be a better solution.

My hack breaks the `'uncomment-region`.  A proper fix would be to change `'comment-padright`.  That would take a little more research so as not to break other things.  The above hack only changes behavior in `'c-mode` (adjust the condition to your liking).

Comment: The only thing Google gives me for "comment-styles" is

http://emacsbugs.donarmstrong.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=3371

Emacs C-h a comment-styles doesn't give anything either.

Comment: It's defined in Emacs 23.1, are you using an older version?

Comment: I am using the Emacs which came with Ubuntu/FreeBSD. On Windows I have Emacs 23.1 but I am using FreeBSD right now and it says 22.3.1. Anyway your example worked, so thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Closest I could find with the built-in commenting support is if you set `comment-style` to `multi-line`, which will produce this:

```
/* This is a comment which extends
 * over more than one line in C. */
```

If that isn't close enough, take a look at `newcomment.el` and define your own commenting functions as appropriate.