# In emacs, can I get comment-region to use a block comment instead of commenting each line?

Tags: xml, emacs

I have an XML file; opens in nxml-mode in emacs 23.2.

would like `comment-region` to comment the region as a block, rather than comment each line in the region. It makes for a more readable commented section, in my opinion.

Before:

[image]

After `comment-region':

[image]

Desired After:

[image]

In curly-brace languages like JavaScript and Java, comment-region comments each line, but I find this ok, because it uses the one-line comment prefix, `//` , which preserves the readability of what follows.  For XML I'd like it to be different.

---

**Edit**:

I just saw Trey's old answer regarding a similar question for c-mode: [Emacs comment-region in C mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551854/emacs-comment-region-in-c-mode)   Basically there's a new module called `newcomment.el` which defines a bunch of commenting styles.

This looks promising, but it is not fully sorted with nxml-mode. For example, when I tried `box-multi` as a style, the commented section looked good but `C-u comment-region` did not reverse what had been added. :/   Likewise with `box` style.   I'll fiddle around with it some more.

---

**Edit #2**

Here's the code I used, [thanks to Alex Ott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17028959/48082).

```
(defun dino-xml-comment-region (beg end &optional arg)
  (interactive "*r\nP")
  (if (> beg end)
      (let (tmp) (setq tmp beg beg end end tmp)))
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region beg end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (cond
       ;; is there a C-u prefix?
       ((and (listp arg) (> (length arg) 0))
        (and (re-search-forward "<!-- *[\n\r]" nil t)
             (goto-char (- (point-max) 1))
             (re-search-backward " *-->" nil t)
             (goto-char (point-min))
             (progn
               (re-search-forward "<!-- *[\n\r]" nil t)
               (replace-match "")
               (goto-char (- (point-max) 1))
               (re-search-backward "[\n\r] *-->" nil t)
               (replace-match ""))))

       (t
        (insert "<!--\n")
        (goto-char (- (point-max) 1))
        (unless (= 10 (following-char))
          (forward-char))
        (insert "\n-->"))))))
```

Then, in my nxml-mode-fn, I did this:

```
(local-set-key "\C-c\C-c"  'dino-xml-comment-region)
```

Actual behavior: 
[image]

Be careful, though: this is completely naive and does not try to "escape" intervening comment starts and stops within the region.  If anyone feels the urge to add that to the code above, I'd appreciate it but I won't worry about it further myself.

Comment: @wvxvw - oooooo, that's a sad thing. You're just teasing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be something like:

```
(defun xml-comment-region (beg end &optional arg)
  (interactive "*r\nP")
  (if (> beg end)
      (let (mid) (setq mid beg beg end end mid)))
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region beg end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (insert "<!-- ")
      (goto-char (- (point-max) 1))
      (unless (= 10 (following-char))
    (forward-char))
      (insert " -->"))))
```

bound it to any key in `xml-mode` hook...

Comment: Thansk Alex.  I doctored that up a bit to get my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might get some mileage out of something like

```
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'comment-style) 'multi-line)
            (set (make-local-variable 'comment-continue) " ")))
```

Comment: That worked pretty well, @Stefan, thank you. The only problem is when removing the comments the XML gets completely un-formatted, all the previous indentation goes away and every angle bracket moves over to column zero. An unfortunate side-effect. I will play around with this, too. I may be able to fix it by re-indenting the region in after-advice.